# c# listener stream read json - how to know the data are complete now

Tags: c#, json, stream, tcplistener

I would really appreciate making more clear to me how I can recognize the JSON data arrived through TcpListener (GetStream()) Read() (into some buffer) and are either complete or corrupted? I thought the TcpListener is more user-friendly way than the Socket class usage.

I can put a buffer into which I will be putting the arriving data and at each '\n' character I will check whether the JSON is complete and valid. But what if something happens in the middle of some JSON and I will be mixing the previous incomplete JSON message with the next JSON message?

Or am I completely wrong in my thoughts and the Read() function of the TcpListener stream is giving me only completed data every time?

Could you please advise me how it is, because in sockets there is no sure thing that the message will arrive at one event in other languages like CPP (so I need to buffer it until delimiter character)? When I test, it seems the JSON message arrives at one Read() call, I cannot simulate the opposite behavior, so I want to be ensured about that.

Comment: TCP guarantees correct order of bytes. So if you check for delimiter character, you can be sure that everything up to this point has been sent/received correctly. However, this requires to add unique delimiter character. I also expected TcpListener to be easier to use.

Comment: Note that sending the count of bytes before the data might be a better alternative to a delimiter character because this way it is not necessary to check every byte for the delimiter character. Also normal data could be mistaken for the delimiter character.